# Angular 7 - Forzar un Ctrl F5 al cargar en el browser

Tags: angular7

Tengo una app en produccion, con **Angular 7**. Todo va relativamente bien con dicha app. El inconveniente se presenta al momento de realizar un **update** de la aplicacion, ya sea por mejoras o por corrección de algún bug. Sucede que cuando pongo una nueva versión, los clientes que la utilizan no siempre ven la versión correcta que acabo de subir... normalmente tienen que hacer un `CTRL+F5` para que se refresque el browser y se cargue la versión correcta. Yo inicialmente generaba mi `dist` con el siguiente comando:

```
ng build --prod
```

Luego leí que eso no me generaba el nombre random de la finalización de los archivos en el `dist` y que por eso el browser no se daba cuenta. A partir de ahí genero el `dist` de la siguiente manera:

```
ng build -- --prod --aot --output-hashing=all
```

Esto hace que cada vez que yo genero el `dist`, los archivos tienen una terminación en el nombre distinta de este tipo:

```
main.73082dfd8ed71ec3f92d.js
```

Siempre la ultima parte del nombre del archivo `main.js` va cambiando, pero de todas maneras, cuando abro el browser después de haber actualizado la app, no siempre me ejecuta la ultima versión.

> ¿Existe alguna manera, mediante programación, que yo pueda detectar que la versión que estoy ejecutando no es la correcta y forzar un `CTRL+F5` desde el código?.

Gracias de antemano

Comment: Creo que [esto](https://angular.io/guide/service-worker-config) te puede ayudar

Answer (score 0):

Prueba con esto!:

```
ng build --prod --outputHashing=all
```

nota: funciona cuando re-inicias el Navegador!

Comment: Esto no provee una respuesta a la pregunta. Cuando tengas suficiente reputación podrás dejar comentarios en cualquier publicación. Saludos